# Facebook app_scoped_user_id duplicate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

Alright, strange problem that I'm encountering:

Our website uses Facebook to log in. Currently I'm using HybridAuth to get the user's information - I'm storing the identifier ('app_scoped_user_id' as I've now learned), and using it to check when people try to sign up or login through Facebook.

A few weeks ago, we went through a total rebranding of the site, separate domain entirely. I ended up creating a second Facebook app through their developer console for the new domain, because it wouldn't let me add that domain in the settings of the original one. I wasn't aware that the identifier coming back was within scope of that particular app - hoping that this won't be a major hurdle to fix.

So a problem occurred where a user went to sign up with Facebook, and was logged in as an existing user who had signed up under the old domain - so the app_scoped_user_id for this new user matched the app_scoped_user_id for the old user and signed them in. Clearly an issue.

Now the weird part is that for old users who had signed in through the original app are signing in fine through the new app - definitely sending through the new keys, connecting to the new app, but apparently the app_scoped_user_id being returned is identical between the two apps.

SO... am I not understanding things properly? If the app_scoped_user_id is different between two Facebook apps, is it possible to bring over the used ids from one app to the other?

EDIT******

Problem solved... if anyone else ends up making the same silly mistake I made, this is how I solved it:

Since the info coming back from Facebook includes their e-mail... just checking their e-mail field to see if they already exist, and assigning the new token to that entry. Obviously there could be a few cases where either the user changed their email on Facebook, or changed their email within our app, but our user base isn't too large yet, so glad to set this right now.

Comment: App scoped user ids should always be different between apps. There is no way to bring over ids from one app to the other. If you have an id that is same in both apps something is wrong. Can you give an example of one of those ids and I can check it out

Comment: I think you misunderstood - 

app A: user signs up, app_scoped_user_id stored on our DB.

app B: user signs up, app_scoped_user_id matches existing id in the DB, signs in as some other user

Comment: They will not match. Then you are doing something wrong or there is a bug in Facebook. Can you give an example of an id that behaves like this?